# Tanstack Router - How to pass value from another context

Tags: typescript, react-context, tanstack-router

I'm building a react app that is using Tanstack router, and I'd like to access values from a context provider that I created over to the router `beforeLoad` handler for a given route. My app structure looks like this:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AppProvider>
      <RouteProvider />
    </AppProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

And the RouteProvider component definition is this:

```
import { RouterProvider as TSRouteProvider } from '@tanstack/react-router';
...

const RouteProvider: FC = () => {
  const { user, signedIn, loaded } = useApp();

  if (!loaded) {
     return null;
  }

  return <TSRouteProvider router={router} context={{ user, signedIn }} />;
};

export default RouteProvider;
```

You can see above that I'm trying to use the context prop to pass values from my custom app context hook into the Tanstack router, however the tanstack router context never seems to receive the updated values. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Also experiencing the same issue with Clerk's user auth when passing them into the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **TLDR use `router.invalidate()` when the context data changes.**

The `RouteProvider` is not a real React Context, so it is basically static, however you can `invalidate` it, thus triggering a refresh.

> Note this refreshes all the router caches, including `beforeLoad` and `loader`, so they will have to reload data again. Therefore don't put too much in the `RouterContext` as you want to only call `invalidate` when you really have to, such as user logout etc.

A good way to handle this is with a single object behind a `useMemo`:

```
const routerContext = useMemo(() => {
    return {
        user,
        signedIn
    };
}, [
    user,
    signedIn
]);
```

Now with `useEffect` you then `invalidate` the `routerContext` anytime it changes, now the `routerContext` should work in your `beforeLoad` and `loader` functions.

```
useEffect(() => {
    router.invalidate();
}, [routerContext]);
```

And pass it in to `RouterProvider`:

```
return [...] <RouterProvider router={router} context={routerContext} />
```

It's insane that this is buried in the Tanstack Example here: https://tanstack.com/router/latest/docs/framework/react/examples/kitchen-sink-react-query-file-based, but not mentioned anywhere in the Tanstack docs for **Router Context** right now: https://tanstack.com/router/v1/docs/framework/react/guide/router-context.